# Why my js date starts calculating wrong around november?

Tags: javascript, datetime

My code behaves funny when I try to add days close to 30 November (any year):

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days){
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
    return this;
};

function calculateDate(string_date, days_to_add){
    var arr, dat;

    arr = string_date.split(" ");
    dat = new Date(2013, (("enefebmarabrmayjunjulagosepoctnovdic".indexOf(arr[1])+3)/3), (((arr[0].charAt(0)!="0")?arr[0]:arr[0].substring(1))*1));
    dat.addDays(days_to_add*1);

    return (dat.getDate() + "/" + dat.getMonth() + "/"+dat.getFullYear());
}
```

Now if I use:

- `calculateDate("07 nov",24);` returns `31/11/2013` (my calendar says this 2013 November stops at 30)
- `calculateDate("07 nov",25);` returns `1/0/2014`

My code seems to work fine with any other months and dates, so why is my code not working near November-December properly? Have computers developed feelings and demand holidays in order to keep working?

Comment: You want to remove the `+3`. The month parameter is zero-based.

Comment: And you want to use a simple `parseInt(arr[0], 10)` instead of that complex expression for the day

Comment: `(((x+3)/3)-1)` it is, thanks

Comment: …which is equal to just `(x/3)` :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `Date` object [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) is a zero-based index:

Notice how "November" has 31 days?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript `Date` the month fraction is zero-based

So 11th month is December

Comment: @PHPglue: it annoys, seriously

Answer (score 1):

Your month is not zero-based, but it should be in JS [`Date` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Use this for creating the date object:

```
dat = new Date(2013,
               "enefebmarabrmayjunjulagosepoctnovdic".indexOf(arr[1])/3,
               parseInt(arr[0], 10)
);
```

and then

```
return dat.getDate() + "/" + (dat.getMonth()+1) + "/" + dat.getFullYear();
```

Comment: and `dat.getMonth()+1` in the return, thanks your suggestions worked perfectly

Comment: The Math is still wrong, but you are correct. PHPglue has it right.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you add 3 to the `indexOf()`. `indexOf('nov')` is 32 + 1 would be 33. Also, `Date.getMonth()` is a 0-11 index.

Try something like:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days){
  this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
  return this;
}
function calculateDate(string_date, days_to_add){
  var arr = string_date.split(' ');
  var dat = new Date(2013, ('janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec'.indexOf(arr[1])+1)/3, +(arr[0].charAt(0) !== '0' ? arr[0] : arr[0].substring(1)));
  dat.addDays(+days_to_add);
  return (dat.getDate() + '/' + (dat.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dat.getFullYear());
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/PHPglue/V3hYQ/3/ for a working example. Of course, your format is Day/Month/Year.

By the way, you can just put `+` in front of a String to cast it to a number.